# Parse Android Get Email doesn't return it

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, parse-platform

I know there is quite a lot of question about that topic already but I tried many of them without having succeed in retrieving my own email address.

I'd like to know if I did something wrong and/or there is some obvious solution to the problem I am facing.

So here is how I get the Auth Token via Parse SDK (on Android):

```
List<String> permissions = Arrays.asList("email", "public_profile");
                ParseFacebookUtils.logInWithReadPermissionsInBackground(SignupActivity.this, permissions, new LogInCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void done(ParseUser user, ParseException err) {
                        if (user == null) {
                            Log.d("MyApp", "Uh oh. The user cancelled the Facebook login.");
                            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(SignupActivity.this);
                            builder.setTitle("Fail");
                            builder.setMessage("Looks like a cancellation");
                            builder.show();
                        } else {
                            makeMeRequest();
                        }
                    }
                });
```

At the beginning, I naively thought that doing a simple `ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getEmail()` would have be enough to get the email but it wasn't (quite fascinating when you know that Parse belongs to Facebook). But then, I decided to create a Me request to Graph API directly. It looks like this:

```
 private void makeMeRequest() {
        GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),
                new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted(JSONObject jsonObject, GraphResponse graphResponse) {
                        if (jsonObject != null) {
                            JSONObject userProfile = new JSONObject();
                            Log.d(TAG, jsonObject.toString());
                            try {
                                ParseUser currentUser = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();

                                userProfile.put("facebookId", jsonObject.getLong("id"));
                                userProfile.put("name", jsonObject.getString("name"));

                                if (jsonObject.has("gender"))
                                    userProfile.put("gender", jsonObject.getString("gender"));

                                if (jsonObject.has("email"))
                                    currentUser.setEmail(jsonObject.getString("email"));

                                // Save the user profile info in a user property
                                currentUser.put("profile", userProfile);
                                currentUser.saveInBackground();

                                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(SignupActivity.this);
                                builder.setTitle("Success");
                                builder.setMessage("Logged in with Facebook!\nDetails:\n" + currentUser.getEmail());
                                builder.show();
                                Log.d("MyApp", "User signed up and logged in through Facebook!");

                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                Log.d(TAG,
                                        "Error parsing returned user data. " + e);
                            }
                        } else if (graphResponse.getError() != null) {
                            switch (graphResponse.getError().getCategory()) {
                                case LOGIN_RECOVERABLE:
                                    Log.d(TAG,
                                            "Authentication error: " + graphResponse.getError());
                                    break;

                                case TRANSIENT:
                                    Log.d(TAG,
                                            "Transient error. Try again. " + graphResponse.getError());
                                    break;

                                case OTHER:
                                    Log.d(TAG,
                                            "Some other error: " + graphResponse.getError());
                                    break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });

        request.executeAsync();
    }
```

As some good observers could have noticed, that's not my code it comes from another thread/github/gist (made too much tries, cannot remember!). The problem with that is that it returns me:

> {"name":"Laurent Meyer","id":"10205968929559630"}

which is pretty nice (better than nothing), but not my email address.

The question is then: did I do some mistake on my code or the problem come from my Facebook settings (another cause could be that I'm using a test version of my FB app)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, `GraphRequest.newMeRequest` returns the default fields `id` and `name`. To get other fields, you need to specify the required fields before your call to `request.executeAsync()`:

```
Bundle params = new Bundle();
params.putString("fields", "name,id,email");
request.setParameters(params);
```

Comment: I may have tried that but got an exception, I'll confirm you that in the next days.